# seleccionar botones y llene datagridview c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, programación-bajo-nivel

```
       public void productos() { 

        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();
        SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=proyecto1;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlDataAdapter dax = new SqlDataAdapter("select pro.nombre, pro.precio from producto pro inner join estado est on pro.ID_estado=est.ID_estado where est.ID_estado='1'", cnx);
        //select pro.nombre, pro.precio from producto pro inner join estado est on pro.ID_estado=est.ID_estado where est.ID_estado='1'
        DataTable dtx = new DataTable();
        dax.Fill(dtx);

        for (int i = 0; i < dtx.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Button btnx = new Button();
            btnx.Name = "btnx" + dtx.Rows[i][0];         
            btnx.Tag = dtx.Rows[i][0];


           btnx.Text = dtx.Rows[i][0].ToString();


            btnx.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12f,      FontStyle.Regular);

            btnx.BackColor = Color.Gold;
            btnx.Height = 100;
            btnx.Width = 150;

            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(btnx);



        }
```

este código genera los botones con los datos que tengo en sql server y no logro seleccionar un botón y que lleve los datos de nombre y precio al datagridview

he intentado crear variables para saber que valor tiene pero no lo acepta

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO en español. Edita la pregunta, e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta gracias, lo edite para que se pueda comprender mejor